# How to not display a destination in jetpack navigation?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I have these screens:

```
NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = AuthScreen.route
) {
    composable(
        route = AuthScreen.route
    ) {
        AuthScreen()
    }
    composable(
        route = MainScreen.route
    ) {
        MainScreen()
    }
}
```

In the MainActivity, I need to send the user to the right screen according to the auth state. So I use:

```
val isUserSignedOut = viewModel.getAuthState().collectAsState().value
if (isUserSignedOut) {
    navController.navigate(AuthScreen.route) {
        popUpTo(navController.graph.id) {
            inclusive = true
        }
    }
} else {
    navController.navigate(MainScreen.route) {
        popUpTo(navController.graph.id) {
            inclusive = true
        }
    }
}
```

And everything works as expected, because I think that this is a synchronous operation. Now, when the user is authenticated, I need to create a request to check the type of user. Here is what I have tried:

```
if (isUserSignedOut) {
    navController.navigate(AuthScreen.route) {
        popUpTo(navController.graph.id) {
            inclusive = true
        }
    }
} else {
    Request(
        checkAdmin = { admin ->
            if (admin) {
                navController.navigate(AdminScreen.route) {
                    popUpTo(navController.graph.id) {
                        inclusive = true
                    }
                }
            } else {
                navController.navigate(MainScreen.route) {
                    popUpTo(navController.graph.id) {
                        inclusive = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

The problem with this code is that when I open the app, first time I get the `AuthScreen` displayed, even if the user is authenticated. In other words, while I get the response of the asynchronous request, the `AuthScreen` is displayed and I don't want that. I need go to the `MainScreen` or `AdminScreen` without displaying the `AuthScreen` first. How to solve this?

---

Edit:

@BenjyTec I'm getting the auth state from the ViewModel:

```
fun getAuthState() = authRepo.getAuthState(viewModelScope)
```

And here is the repo:

```
override fun getAuthState(viewModelScope: CoroutineScope) = callbackFlow {
    val listener = FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener { auth ->
        trySend(auth.currentUser == null)
    }
    auth.addAuthStateListener(listener)
    awaitClose {
        auth.removeAuthStateListener(listener)
    }
}.stateIn(
    scope = viewModelScope,
    started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),
    initialValue = auth.currentUser == null
)
```

Comment: If you have a viewmodel in place, I can suggest to check the auth status of the user before navigating to the start destination which is the auth screen. Then, according to the auth status, you can choose an appropriate start destination.

Comment: @tomerpacific This is exactly what I'm doing. I have added the way I'm getting the `isUserSignedOut` value from the ViewModel. Can you please check? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring the initial value of your Flow like this:

```
initialValue = auth.currentUser == null
```

So before the async callback completes, your `isUserSignedOut` will already be `true`. As a result, the `AuthScreen` will be shown immediately.

You will have to introduce a third state:

- User is logged in
- User is not logged in
- Loading

While the App performs the asynchronous request, initially set the state to "loading" and display a loading Composable then.

You can create an enumeration to represent the different states:

```
enum class UIState{
    LOADING, LOGGEDIN, NOTLOGGEDIN
}
```

Then declare your Flow like this:

```
override fun getAuthState(viewModelScope: CoroutineScope) = callbackFlow {
    val listener = FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener { auth ->
        if (auth.currentUser == null) {
            trySend(UIState.NOTLOGGEDIN)
        } else {
            trySend(UIState.LOGGEDIN)
        }
    }
    auth.addAuthStateListener(listener)
    awaitClose {
        auth.removeAuthStateListener(listener)
    }
}.stateIn(
    scope = viewModelScope,
    started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),
    initialValue = UIState.LOADING
)
```

And in your Composable:

```
var uiState by viewModel.getAuthState().collectAsState()

if (uiState.equals(UIState.LOADING) {
    // show loading Composable
    // (or do nothing if you set the loading Composable as startDestination)
} else if (uiState.equals(UIState.NOTLOGGEDIN) {
    // navigate to AuthScreen Composable
} else {
   // navigate to MainScreen Composable
}
```

If you want the logic happen at the very start of the App, you can also set the loading Composable as `startDestination` of the NavHost and then navigate when the state becomes `LOGGEDIN` or `NOTLOGGEDIN`.

You can also write above logic as a `when` clause:

```
when (uiState) {
    UIState.LOADING -> {/** show loading Composable **/}
    UIState.NOTLOGGEDIN -> {/** navigate to AuthScreen Composable **/}
    UIState.LOGGEDIN -> { /** navigate to MainScreen Composable **/ }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. So you basically say at A), that I should create another `LoadingScreen` that should be displayed while getting the data from the server, right?

Comment: Basically yes. I don't in which context you are performing that logic, but it could also be enough to directly show a loading Composable in there and not navigate at all.

Comment: Does it make any difference the way in getting the `isAdmin`? I use `val isUserSignedOut = viewModel.getAuthState().collectAsState().value`. I just updated my question.

Comment: When you use a StateFlow, the Flow will also contain an initial value for a short moment. You would need to show the loading Composable while this initial value is returned by the Flow. I don't know where you declare your Flow, but in the `MutableStateFlow` constructor, you can pass an initial value. You could pass `MutableStateFlow(UIState.Loading)` there. Then use approach B as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: You are welcome, I hope this helps! Where exactly is your StateFlow coming from? Are you initializing it somewhere yourself? I can then update my answer to match your situation better.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much. I just updated my question to make it more clear.

Comment: @TheOne I updated my answer. I think it should work that way, although I can't test it right now. But at least it should give you an idea.

Comment: I'll try tomorrow and I'll get back to you. Thank you again.

Comment: Your approach is very clean. But I think I got a simpler solution. I have just created a `LoadingScreen` which I have set it as a `startDestination`. Now, when I open the app, for a few seconds, the `LoadingScreen` is displayed until I'm redirected to right screen. Does it make sense to you? Btw, just voted-up.

Comment: @TheOne This is a smart solution! I will include this in my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting AuthScreen displayed at startup even when the user is authenticated because it's your start destination.
I suggest adding a Splash screen and making it your start destination, it will be shown while you're making the network call.